# Automatically execute parent method before overriding method without using constructors/destructors or explicitly calling it in derived method

Tags: c++

So first the setup. say I have two classes, **Parent** and **Child**:

**Parent.h**

```
#ifndef PARENT_H_
#define PARENT_H_

#include <string>

class Parent {
public:
    Parent();
    virtual ~Parent();

    virtual void doStuff();   //method to be overridden
    static std::string stuff; //string that I want to fill in the correct order, initialized with ""
};

#endif /* PARENT_H_ */
```

**Child.h**

```
#ifndef CHILD_H_
#define CHILD_H_

#include "Parent.h"

class Child: public Parent {
public:
    Child();
    virtual ~Child();

    void doStuff();
};

#endif /* CHILD_H_ */
```

The `doStuff()` function in **Parent**:

```
void Parent::doStuff()
{
    std::cout << "PARENT DOES STUFF \n" << std::endl;
}
```

And in the **Child** class `doStuff()` will accordingly have to execute

```
std::cout << "CHILD DOES STUFF \n" << std::endl;
```

**Now onto my question:**

Is there a way to automatically execute `Parent::doStuff()` anytime before `Child::doStuff()` is being done, and that **without explicitly calling it anywhere else than in the Parent and without using constructors/destructors**?
So not in the `main()` function and not in `Child::doStuff()`, for example.

*I know this can work with calling each `doStuff()` method in the constructor of its corresponding class, but I was specifically asked not to do it in that way*

**Edit:** the std::cout code snippet from `Child::doStuff()` would have to be done in that function, of course.

Comment: The short answer is: no there isn't. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: So where do you suppose to be called exactly?

Comment: Also, if your design requires the users of these classes to call `doStuff` before they can call other methods, rethink your prohibition on special member functions, or write a free function like `std::unique_ptr<Parent> make_child()`

Answer (score 0):

```
class Parent
{
public:
   void doStuff()
   {
      std::cout << "PARENT DOES STUFF \n" << std::endl;
      internalDoStuff();
   }

protected:
   virtual void internalDoStuff() {}

}

class Child : public Parent
{
protected:
   void internalDoStuff()
   {
      std::cout << "CHILD DOES STUFF \n" << std::endl;
   }
}
```

This is to respect your statement

> without explicitly calling it anywhere else than in the Parent and
>   without using constructors/destructors

Is not called in costructor/destructor.

Is not explicitely called in chid class.

Is automatically called when you call child.doStuff()

Comment: Thank you, but I´m afraid the "CHILD DOES STUFF \n" output has to be done in Child::doStuff(), i tried to clarify that in the question.

Comment: FYI, this is known as the [Non-Virtual Interface](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Non-Virtual_Interface) pattern.

Comment: @Quentin, precisely.

Comment: @Moia I meant that the actual line `std::cout << "CHILD DOES STUFF \n" << std::endl;` has to stay within `Child::doStuff`. I´m sorry if that wasn´t quite clear in the Edit or my comment

Comment: @MaxK. is it not literally inside Child::doStuff, but it is Always called in Child::doStuff. Otherwise what you ask is inapplicable

Comment: @Moia Ok, then it actually seems to be impossible. Thank you!